# Each works but Bind dosen't why?

Tags: jquery

Hi have  a function to console the array, and it works fine.

this is my function :

```
var arrayLength = outFitLinks.length-1;
    var depthCount = 0;
    for(i=1;i<=arrayLength;i++){
        $('.cloneFrame').clone().removeClass('cloneFrame').each(function(){
            i % 2 == 1 ? $(this).attr('id','id'+i).appendTo('.front') : $(this).attr('id','id'+i).appendTo('.back');
            $(this).find('.product-frame').each(function(index){
                depthCount += 1;
                $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'imgs/outfits/'+depthCount+'.jpg');
                $(this).find('a').each(function(){
                    console.log(outFitLinks[i][index]); 
                })
                $(this).parent().hide();
            })
        })

    }
    $('.cloneFrame').remove();
```

at the same function i changed to console to bind to click event, it's not working.. anything wrong?

this is the function not working :

```
var arrayLength = outFitLinks.length-1;
    var depthCount = 0;
    for(i=1;i<=arrayLength;i++){
        $('.cloneFrame').clone().removeClass('cloneFrame').each(function(){
            i % 2 == 1 ? $(this).attr('id','id'+i).appendTo('.front') : $(this).attr('id','id'+i).appendTo('.back');
            $(this).find('.product-frame').each(function(index){
                depthCount += 1;
                $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'imgs/outfits/'+depthCount+'.jpg');
                $(this).find('a').bind('click', function(){
                    console.log(outFitLinks[i][index]); // not working  
                })
                $(this).parent().hide();
            })
        })

    }
    $('.cloneFrame').remove();
```

Comment: Any reason you aren't using `$(this).find('a').click(function(){})` ?

Comment: Just a hint: There is a ';' missing - but its in both examples. Maybe not the problem

Comment: i need to attach a click event on that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because the event handler runs later, when the variable `i` (and possibly `outFitLinks`) has a different value from when the event was bound.

Create a closure, so that you can preserve each value for later in a local variable:

```
(function() {
  var links = outFitLinks[i][index];
  $(this).find('a').bind('click', function(){
    console.log(links);
  });
})();
```

Come to think of it, you already have a closure in this case, as you are using `.each` for the loop, so it should be enough with:

```
var links = outFitLinks[i][index];
$(this).find('a').bind('click', function(){
  console.log(links);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using `.click(...)` instead of `bind("click", ...)` ?
I've had some strange things happening in one but not the other, wort a try to change it I think :)

Comment: `.click()` uses `.bind('click', ...)` internally. It's just a helper method.